# can't import python dictionary from a text file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i'm trying to import data from a text file as a dictionnary in Python, but i'm stuck.

```
{001 : {"firstname":'A',"field-lastname":'B',"field-birthday":'01011970'},
002 : {"field-firstname":'C','field-lastname':'D',"field-birthday":'01011970'}}
```

I tried with `json.load` and `json.loads` but it's raising errors.

I would like to import the file as a dict. Check if some data `003 : {"firstname":'Z',"field-lastname":'Y',"field-birthday":'01011970'}` is already in the data set. If not, append it to the dict and write the new data set in the file.

Comment: That's invalid JSON.

Comment: It is always helpful if you post your errors.

Comment: Specifically, JSON doesn't allow integer-like keys or single quotes for string values, (you have to use double quotes). You can validate your json here: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is not a JSON it's seems like a `dict` that printed out(if `001` be `1` and `002` be `2` it's a python `dict`).

I suggest write this in JSON format but, if you want to read the `dict` you can use `eval` function to do that.

```py
with open("data.dict", 'r') as f:
    mydata = eval(f.read())
    print(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the structure is invalid. An alternative strucure will be:

```
{"001" : {"firstname":"A","field-lastname":"B","field-birthday":"01011970"},
"002" : {"field-firstname":"C","field-lastname":"D","field-birthday":"01011970"}}
```